# Motor will not crank

Tags: engine

I cranked my motor up and it was running then it started making a funny sound so i cut it off and tried to crank it up again and it would never crank. What would be the main reason for it not cranking?

Comment: Do we not have a duplicate for a generic question like this? I’ve seen many, but did not know which one would the better to pick for a duplicate vote.

Comment: It's possibly duplicate (and too vague to answer well as-is) but would be a decent non-duplicate question if it were edited to reflect the specific vehicle.

Comment: Make sure it has oil...

Answer (score 1):

If the engine cranks (turns over with the starter) but doesn't run (engine stops turning when the starter stops) It's usually one of three problems:

- Fuel - spray short bursts of starting fluid (ether) in the intake while cranking the vehicle. If the vehicle runs while you are spraying the starting fluid the vehicles fuel system should be checked
- Fire (spark) - Pull a spark plug off and hold it close to metal (ground) have someone crank the engine and look for spark. If you have no spark check the ignition system.
- Mechanical - You may have a mechanical problem like a blown head gasket, broken timming chain or belt, broken crankshaft, or broken camshaft just to name a few.

It sounds like yours may be mechanical based on the noise prior to you turning off the engine.

This answer is based entirely on the assumption that you have a gasoline engine and not a diesel. It would help if you would edit your answer to include make model year and engine size.